# Do Adobe RGB and sRGB assume 2 degree observer?

Tags: color-conversion, rgb, color-spaces

I know that Adobe RGB and sRGB assume D65 illumination, but do they assume a 2 degree or 10 degree [standard observer](https://sensing.konicaminolta.us/blog/understanding-standard-observers-in-color-measurement/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **sRGB:** 2°
- **Adobe RGB:** 2°

### sRGB

From [A Standard Default Color Space for the Internet - sRGB](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB.html) (Version 1.10, November 5, 1996):

> The colorimetric definitions provide the transforms necessary to convert between the sRGB color space **and the CIEXYZ two degree observer color space**.

### Adobe RGB

From [Adobe RGB (1998) Color Image Encoding](https://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/AdobeRGB1998.pdf) (Version 2005-05 May 2005):

> All chromaticity values shall be based on **the CIE 1931 two-degree standard observer.** See CIE Publication 15.2

Answer (score 1):

As per the [specification](http://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/AdobeRGB1998.pdf) of Adobe RGB assumes 2 degree standard observer.

I dont have access to sRGB specification at the moment (i have at work but i wont be there for a while). But i believe it is a 2 degree observer as well.